# Array has values in it, but not able to access them, what might be the problem?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I get two values(string) by a callback function, suppose those 2 values are a and b, so now I will push those values in array. When I console.log this array, it is displaying those value only when I expand the array by clicking on arrow symbol. When I try to access the index value, it says undefined. So I guess there is an issue function calling?

```
funcOuter() {
    let newList =[];
    this.calledFunc(function (param) {
        newList.push(param);
    });
    console.log(newList[1]);
}
```

Actual Output:

> undefined

Expected Output:

> 123.234.556

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok..sure. Please tell me which part of my question is not understood.I will change it ASAP.

Comment: what's the param value you are passing in?

Comment: You should post something we can verify, and even execute in order to validate your problem.

Comment: param values are two typeof-strings : num1  num2

Comment: @Ele sure...! will try to create on stackblitz

Comment: you have an async call there probably, and the answer is not ready when you do console.log

Comment: @Vega oh..  Yep that might be the problem.

Comment: What's `this.somecomponent.CalledFunc`? Should also be using arrow syntax to avoid having `this` context issue

Comment: @penleychan I didn't get you . Using arrow syntax, will avoid this context issue?

Comment: in js we use camelCase for function names

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html more info on `this`. Gotta scroll down to it.

Comment: Doesn't really going to solve the issue tho, I still haven't got a slightest idea how `this.calledFunc()` works, you need to provide the code for that part how it works

Comment: This is for async call, you can return the value inside the function instead of log, and use the return function value where you need.

Comment: @SrikrushnaPal so.. replacing console.log with returning array and giving that callback function a name and use it where I want..right?

Comment: Yes @rahul. Javascript provide many ways to handle  this type of synario.

Comment: I did it !! thanks for your help guys!!! I just used var that = this,i.e I wanted to access the OuterFunc data inside the callback func, so I just incuded the outerFunc data insde the callbackfunc declaring var that = this in Outerfunc. I would be glad to know if there is any other solution!! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you use angular 2+, why has callback function, i think it's a solution.

```
export class AchievementComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async funcOuter() {
    let newList =[];
    const param = await this.funcInner();
    newList.push(param);
  }

  funInner() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      this.calledFunc((param)=>{
         resolve(param);
      })
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Ok..I think this will work too, because its wating till the called func gets its params. But I got the solution. Anyway thanks for giving me your precious time!!

Comment: you are welcome, I think if you use the arrow function, you don't need to declare var that = this

Answer (score 0):

**Best is to visualize code execution:**

Stack **S**

Heap **H**

Queue **Q**

On execution your `funcOuter` is put on **S**

As are the assignment, function call and log:

**S**: `funcOuter`, `let newList =[];`

Assignment gets executed ...

**S**: `funcOuter`, `this.calledFunc(callback);`

function gets executed ...

**S**: `funcOuter`, `this.calledFunc(callback);`, `calledFunc inner block`

inner block and async are done

**S**: `funcOuter`, `console.log(newList[1])`,

**Q**: `possible async calls`

log is done:

**S**: `funcOuter`,

**Q**: `possible async calls`

outer is done:

**S**:

**Q**: `possible async calls`

stack gets filled from Q:

**S**: `callback`,

**Q**: `possibly more async calls`

push gets executed:

**S**: `callback`, `push`

and so on ;)
[Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

So change your code to:

```
funcOuter() {
    let newList =[];
    this.calledFunc(function (param) {
        newList.push(param);
        newList[1] && console.log(newList[1]);
    });

}
```

should give expected results.